# ASP.NET secure download after logging in with Session files contained in ASP.NET directory

Tags: asp.net, file, download, directory, private

Everytime I Type in the exact path to my file I can play it even without being logged in.  I want to make it where I have the files in my computer (not in a database in the computer or someone else's) I log in and I can download them from whatever computer I logged in to my site with.  Direct path I want to be redirected or not available to let download.  Only those logged in can download... even if everyone knows the path to the file.  Possible?  Appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Create an [HttpModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719858%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and on the BeginRequest method check if the request is being made to a file you need to protect, if so, [return a 403 https status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403).

Comment: okay thank you.  where do I put that code though?  I am a bit confused.